# Parsing multiple elements with multiple tags from XML file - edited request

Tags: xml, parsing, beautifulsoup, pubmed-api

I have accessed descriptions of publications from PubMed using their e-utilities using Python. There are many characteristics of each article that I want to extract for each article/author combination the "Id", "Author", "Title" and "DOI"to put into a database for analysis.

Python code I am using:

```
# Proof of concept

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Step 1 - Prepare names to search
# list of members' full names
members_fullname = ['Downs,Stephen M', 'Delaney, Brendan C', 'Grout, Randall W', 'Michaud, Kaleb']

# takes member names and concatenates them to a string
members_concat = ' OR '.join([m+"[Full Author Name]" for m in members_fullname])

# Step 2 - prepares PubMed Entrez "esearch" query
search_term= members_concat
esearch_ids = []
esearch_request = requests.get("http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi",params={'db':'pubmed',"term":search_term,'cmd':"DetailsSearch","reldate":90})
i_esearch_ids = [i.text for i in     BeautifulSoup(esearch_request.text,'lxml-xml').find_all('Id')]
i_esearch_ids += i_esearch_ids

# Step 3 - Takes the results of the Pubmed esearch results         (i_esearch_ids) and submits PubMed Entrez "esummary" request
ids_concat = i_esearch_ids
search_ids = ",".join(ids_concat)
esummary_request = requests.get("https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esummary.fcgi",params={'db':'pubmed','id':search_ids})

# Step 4 Parses esummary results to have id, Author, Title and DOI on single line
from lxml import etree
docs = """esummary_request"""
doc = etree.XML(docs)

for ds in doc.xpath('//DocSum'):
    id = ds.xpath('.//Id/text()')[0]
    title = ds.xpath('.//Item[@Name="Title"]/text()')[0]
    al = [author for author in     ds.xpath('.//Item[@Name="Author"]/text()')]
    print(id,",",title,",",al)
```

gives me errors on the last step:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

File "", line 29, in 
doc = etree.XML(docs)

File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 3236, in lxml.etree.XML

File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1916, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument

File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1796, in lxml.etree._parseDoc

File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1085, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseUnicodeDoc

File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 618, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc

File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 728, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult

File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 657, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError

File "", line 1
XMLSyntaxError: Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1

there is something fundamental that I missing (new to python)

thanks to John and Giles

Answer (score 1):

Since you are dealing with an `xml` file, you should use an `xml` parser, like `lxml`, coupled with `xpath`.

In this case, it can be as simple as:

```
from lxml import etree
docs = """[your xml above]"""
doc = etree.XML(docs)

for ds in doc.xpath('//DocSum'):
    id = ds.xpath('.//Id/text()')[0]
    title = ds.xpath('.//Item[@Name="Title"]/text()')[0]
    al = [author for author in ds.xpath('.//Item[@Name="Author"]/text()')]
    print(id,",",title,",",al)
```

Output:

```
36762609 , Perspectives on ...and Tumor Necrosis Factor ...Study. , ['Ogdie A'...'Michaud K']
36706947 , Impact of key ...United States and Europe. , ['Walsh JA', ... 'Dennis N', 'Gossec L']
```

Comment: When I use from lxml import etree
docs = """esummary_request.text"""
doc = etree.XML(docs)

for ds in doc.xpath('//DocSum'):
    id = ds.xpath('.//Id/text()')[0]
    title = ds.xpath('.//Item[@Name="Title"]/text()')[0]
    al = [author for author in ds.xpath('.//Item[@Name="Author"]/text()')]
    print(id,",",title,",",al)

Comment: File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 3236, in lxml.etree.XML
File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1916, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument
File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1796, in lxml.etree._parseDoc
File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1085, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseUnicodeDoc
File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 618, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc
File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 728, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult
File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 657, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError
File "<string>", line 1

Comment: lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1

Comment: Sorry for the messy text...still learning this community

Comment: @GreggLund  The error message seems to indicate that there is something wrong with the format of your actual file (unlike your sample xml in the question) - for example, it may not actually be well-formed xml. You'll have to fix that issue first before doing anything else.

Comment: Jack - Thank you I will work on that

Comment: I looked at the xml file returned from my request.get to PubMed and it looks good. The xml in the text in my initial question is from that xml.

Comment: Above the first tag there is the following:

Comment: C:\Users\gregg\PycharmProjects\POC022123\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\gregg\PycharmProjects\POC022123\main.py 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE eSummaryResult PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD esummary v1 20041029//EN" "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/eutils/dtd/20041029/esummary-v1.dtd">

Comment: Any suggestions of what I should look at?

Comment: I ran the text of the xml file through an online XML Validator and it did not find any errors

Comment: Sorry for too many messages. I am not passing an external xml file but rather the text of the xml file

Comment: @GreggLund The xml file to be parsed by lxml must be a **clean** xml which starts with `<?xml version="1.0" ...`, etc. Everything before that (`C:\Users\gregg\PycharmProjects\POC022123\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\gregg\PycharmProjects\POC022123\main.py `) needs to be deleted for this to work.

Comment: Jack - Thank you very much for your help
It appears that PyCharm adds the file location on the viewer, but is not part of the xml. I ran this in another environment which does not add show that line in the viewer and i got the same error message

There is something basic I am not understanding about the etree.xml(doc) requirements/behavior. 
I ran the code through a xml validator it says it is ok.
I have tried to pass the actual text (not the variable) to etree.xml(doc) and I get the same results

Comment: When I enter
from lxml import etree
docs = """esummary_request.text"""
doc = etree.XML(docs)

Comment: I get the following:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gregg\PycharmProjects\POC022123\main.py", line 49, in <module>
    doc = etree.XML(docs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 3236, in lxml.etree.XML
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1916, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1796, in lxml.etree._parseDoc
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1085, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseUnicodeDoc
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 618, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 728, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 657, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError
  File "<string>", line 1

Comment: lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1

Comment: On a simpler note. I have reviewed the stackoverflow documentation and I cannot figure out how to keep the formatting on my comments. My apologies

Comment: @GreggLund Let's try a different way: please edit your question and add the exact `requests.get()` you used to obtain the file.

Comment: Jack - thank you very much for your help. I only have my phone until the end of the week when I get to a computer. I will send it then. I assume you mean edit my original question. How do I make sure that the code is formatted on comments?

Comment: Just got to a computer. Thanks for the support!!